# Unable to run iptables commands

Tags: iptables

When I try running

```
sudo iptables -L
```

(or any other iptables related command) I receive the following error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ip_tables': Cannot allocate memory
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I've taken a look at [How can I fix the iptables error message "unable to initialize table 'filter'"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28215/how-can-i-fix-the-iptables-error-message-unable-to-initialize-table-filter) which seems to be very similar to the issue I'm having and based on the instructions from Lekensteyn in that issue I tried

```
sudo modprobe /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko
```

however that also gives an error:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko not found.
```

yet I can clearly see that the iptable_filter.ko exists at the path above...??

Any ideas on how I can resovle this would be (very very) gratefully received...!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sudo iptables -L

You need to use sudo with iptables

Edit: strikthrough due to updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply geoffmcc but the result is still the same even when I sudo...

Comment: Hi geoffmcc, here is no updated answer? Would you like to edit or remove your answer?

Answer (score 0):

With full path need to use insmod:

```
insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I get 

`insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/3.16.0-031600-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko: Cannot allocate memory` 

and I'm still as stuck as I was :-(